# CMake Swig: how to add depencencies on included .i files

Tags: swig

I'm using cmake to create a binding based on swig.

I add my swig library like this.

```
SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY(my_swig_DLL
                                LANGUAGE
                                        Java
                                SOURCES
                                        myfile.i
                                        )
```

Everything works fine but CMake doesn't detect when a change is made on files included in my myfile.i. For example, the myfile. contains the line

```
%include "my_other_file.i"
```

The other file doesn't contain a module by itself but include support code I use in various projects.

How can I make CMake detect a change in my_other_file so it recompiles everything when the file has changed?

Quick note: adding my_other_file.i in the source list generates an error that the file does not contain a %module.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way of achieving this but I found this macro

```
function(watch)
    set_property(
            DIRECTORY
            APPEND
            PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS ${ARGV}
    )
endfunction()
```

So now, I've renamed my included .i files to myinclude.inc_i just so cmake/swig does not process them directly (but at least they appear in my solution), then I "watch" then using the previously defined macro

```
watch(myinclude.inc_i)
```

When myinclude.inc_i if modified, the complete solution is built.